# Update an element of a list of objects in react hooks. Bind an array to a list of select controls

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list

and two components:

```
function ExamenAplicado({alternativas}) {

     const [alternativas, setAlternativas] = useState([{pregunta: 1, alternativa: 0},{pregunta: 2, alternativa: 0},{pregunta: 3, alternativa: 0},{pregunta: 4, alternativa: 0},{pregunta: 5, alternativa: 0}]);

     const handleChange = (e) => {
          setAlternativas({
              ...alternativas,
              [e.target.name] : e.target.value
          })
     }

     return (
        <div className="container my-5">
            <div className="row">
                {alternativas.map(x => ( <ExamenRespuesta key={x.pregunta} numeroPregunta={x.pregunta} handleChange={handleChange} /> ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


function ExamenRespuesta({numeroPregunta, handleChange}) {
    return(
        <div>
            pregunta {numeroPregunta}: 
            <select id={numeroPregunta} name={numeroPregunta} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control">
                <option value="0">vacio</option>    
                <option value="1">a</option>    
                <option value="2">b</option>
                <option value="3">c</option>
                <option value="4">d</option>
                <option value="5">e</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I don't know how to bind the  to each element of the array. So when you change a value of the select, change the value of the "alternativa" field.

The idea is that the pregunta value of the array is linked to the name property of the select and the alternativa value is linked to the value property of the select.

```
pregunta ~~ [select control].name
alternativa ~~ [select control].value
```

Please help. I need an idea of how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the data structure of `alternativas`, you could make it an object where `pregunta` is the key and `alternativa` is the value. Then your `handleChange` function would work as expected.

If `alternativas` must be an array of objects as it appears in your code, then you can create an updated copy of the array using `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAlternativas(
        alternativas.map(value => value.pregunta == e.target.name
            ? { ...value, alternativa: e.target.value }
            : value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [parktomatomi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863938/parktomatomi) mentioned if you can change `alternativas` to an object may be easier to work with.

Otherwise you can do this...

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const actualSelecciónIndice = alternativas.findIndex(el => {
      return el.pregunta === Number(e.target.name)
    })

    let nuevaAlternativas = [...alternativas]

    if(actualSelecciónIndice) {
      nuevaAlternativas[actualSelecciónIndice].alternativa = Number(e.target.value)
      setAlternativas(nuevaAlternativas)
    }
  }
```

not the most elegant solution but works :)